# how to return a list from servlet to my android application

Tags: android

There are some pdf files in my d drive.In my android application I have to return the list of files from a servlet to my activity class,but through my codes it is returning the name of all files as a string.But i need each name separetly.How to do that,

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass data from servlet to android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733177/how-to-pass-data-from-servlet-to-android-application)

Comment: no need of passing data i just want to return file names which are fetched by my servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You a using HTTP to pass data from your servlet to your Android application. HTTP doesn't care about the content of the response, so there is no standard way of defining the structure of the data you are passing. You are pretty much free to do as you please.
One option therefore would be to put your filenames into a comma-separated list in the servlet. In your Android application you chop the String apart into an array of Strings each representing one file name:

```
String[] filenames;
filenames = responseString.split(",");
```

That's the easy way. You could also create XML from your filenames in your servlet, and parse the XML in your Android application. That would look nicer, but it is more work.

Comment: thanks a lot,I got each string separately.Can u please give me how to the same thing using xml file that u have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSONObject`

```
 JSONObject jsEmployeeObj = new JSONObject();


    JSONArray empArray = new JSONArray();

    while (condition) {
    JSONObject jsObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsObject.accumulate("name", res.getString("name"));
    empArray.add(jsObject);

            }


if ((empArray != null) && (empArray.size() > 0)) {
                jsEmployeeObj.accumulate("employeeList", empArray);
            } else {
                jsEmployeeObj.accumulate("employeeList", "empty");
            }

            String output = jsEmployeeObj.toString();
```

return the string ... u can parse JSON in android