# Send arraylist from servlet to Android application

Tags: android, servlets

How can I send a array list from a servlet to an Android application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the point, you need to convert it to a `String` in some standard format which can then be parsed and built using the existing libraries. For example, JSON, XML or CSV, all which are standardized and exchangeable string formats for which a lot of parsing/building libraries exist in a lot of programming languages.

Android has a builtin JSON parser in [the `org.json` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html). It has even a builtin XML parser in [the `org.xml.sax` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html). I'm not sure if there's a builtin CSV library, but there appears to be none. Java EE has in flavor of [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) a great builtin XML parser, but it doesn't have a builtin JSON parser. Only the JAX-RS implementations  (Jersey, RESTeasy, etc) provide a JSON parser. If you can change your servlet to be a JAX-RS webservice instead, you'll have the benefit of being able to return both XML and JSON with very minimal effort. See also [Servlet vs RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful).

Which format to choose depends on the sole functional requirements. For example, is the servlet supposed to be reused for other services? What are the target clients? Etcetera.

In any way, the JSON format is usually more terse and lately more popular than XML, so I'll just give a kickoff example which transfers the data in the JSON format and I'll assume that you really want to do it with a plain vanilla servlet instead of JAX-RS. For this example, you only need to download and drop a JSON library such as [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in `/WEB-INF/lib` in order to convert Java objects to JSON in the servlet.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("item1");
    list.add("item2");
    list.add("item3");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

This will build and return the `List` in the following JSON format:

```
["item1","item2","item3"]
```

This is in turn parseable by `org.json` API in Android as follows:

```
String jsonString = getServletResponseAsStringSomehow(); // HttpClient?
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    list.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
}

// Now you can use `list`.
```

Comment: I realize this is super old, but it was so very helpful I thought I'd still write and ask about a prolem I'm having. I am trying to compile a servlet with the code example above, but I'm getting "error: cannot find symbol | String json = new Gson() etc" (with an arrow pointing at Gson). I didn't know what library to include, so I am using both gson-2.2.3.jar and gson-2.2.3-sources.jar

What could be wrong?

Comment: @Christofer: drop JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Keep sources JAR outside it. Use it only for "attach source" button in IDE. Or, if you're compiling using `javac` command line tool instead of an IDE, add the JAR(s) in `/WEB-INF/lib` fodler to `-cp` or `-classpath` argument.

Comment: I got it working now, I think, by adding an import com.google.gson.Gson statement. Maybe I should have realized this was needed :)

I am compiling via command line, btw. And I actually put the jar files both in the project's WEB-INF/lib as well as the Tomcat server's lib. Maybe this was stupid?

Answer (score 1):

If its a pull based model you can send the HTTP GET request to the servlet endpoint from your android app, and the HTTP Response could be a JSON object, created from an array list.